# Get-ItemProperty Count on 1 result inaccuate?

Tags: powershell

I'm having a weird issue, and it's quite possible that I'm missing something here. 
I have this function:

```
function CheckJava {
    $JavaVersion = (@(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion) | where { $_.DisplayName -like "java*" }).Count
    if ($JavaVersion -eq "" -or $JavaVersion -le 1) {
        Write-Host -NoNewLine "Java Detected - 64bit"
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "  [ NO ]"
        $global:JavaInstalled = $false
    } else {
        Write-Host -NoNewLine "Java Detected - 64bit"
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "  [ YES ]"
        $global:JavaInstalled = $true
    }
}
```

What's interesting, is that if I run this:

```
(@(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion) | where { $_.DisplayName -like "java*" }))
```

I get results. the `.Count` actually works fine, if there are 2 items in the result, but, if there is only one returned result, the `.Count` returns empty. I would expect 1?

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misplaced the array subexpression operator. Change this:

```
(@(Get-ItemProperty ... | Select-Object ...) | where { ... }).Count
```

into this:

```
@(Get-ItemProperty ... | Select-Object ... | where { ... }).Count
```

and the code will do what you expect.

The reason for the behavior you observed is: when the `Get-ItemProperty | Select-Object` pipeline returns just a single result, the `@(...)` turns that result into an array with one element, but the subsequent `| Where-Object` unrolls the array again, so you still end up with a single object instead of an array with one element.

On PowerShell v3 and newer that should still give you a result of 1, though, so you're probably using PowerShell v2 or older.

Comment: I knew it was something simple. :) Thanks Ansgar! Much appreciated!